# MySQL query returns no results with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an issue with PDO and MySQL.
When I send that query to MySQL through phpMyAdmin, it returns 490 rows :

```
SELECT art.AR_Ref AS AR_Ref, art.AR_Design AS AR_Design, art.AR_PrixVen AS AR_PrixVen, art.AR_CodeBarre AS AR_CodeBarre, af.CT_Num AS CT_Num, af.AF_RefFourniss AS AF_RefFourniss, ct.CT_Intitule AS CT_Intitule, art.CL_No1, art.CL_No2, art.CL_No3, art.CL_No4, MATCH (art.indexation) AGAINST ("+:iso*") AS cpt, art.AR_Design REGEXP "^:iso*" AS commencepar, art.AR_Design REGEXP ".+:iso.*" AS contient
FROM f_article art
    LEFT JOIN f_artfourniss af ON (art.AR_Ref = af.AR_Ref AND af.AF_Principal = 1)
    LEFT JOIN f_comptet ct ON (af.CT_Num = ct.CT_Num AND ct.CT_Type = 1)
WHERE art.AR_Sommeil = '0' AND MATCH (art.indexation) AGAINST (("+:iso*") IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY commencepar DESC, contient DESC, cpt DESC, art.AR_Ref
```

But with that code, there are no results at all :

```
<?php
$dbCon = new PDO('mysql:host=SERVER_IP; port=3306; dbname=DATABASE',
    'root',
    'PASSWORD',
    array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
          PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING,
          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

$sql = 'SELECT art.AR_Ref AS AR_Ref, art.AR_Design AS AR_Design, art.AR_PrixVen AS AR_PrixVen, art.AR_CodeBarre AS AR_CodeBarre, af.CT_Num AS CT_Num, af.AF_RefFourniss AS AF_RefFourniss, ct.CT_Intitule AS CT_Intitule, art.CL_No1, art.CL_No2, art.CL_No3, art.CL_No4, MATCH (art.indexation) AGAINST ("+:saisie1*") AS cpt, art.AR_Design REGEXP "^:saisie2*" AS commencepar, art.AR_Design REGEXP ".+:saisie3.*" AS contient FROM f_article art LEFT JOIN f_artfourniss af ON (art.AR_Ref = af.AR_Ref AND af.AF_Principal = 1) LEFT JOIN f_comptet ct ON (af.CT_Num = ct.CT_Num AND ct.CT_Type = 1) WHERE MATCH (art.indexation) AGAINST (("+:saisie4*") IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY commencepar DESC, contient DESC, cpt DESC, art.AR_Ref';
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
$saisie = 'iso';
$stmt->bindParam(':saisie1', $saisie, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':saisie2', $saisie, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':saisie3', $saisie, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':saisie4', $saisie, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
if (($stmt->errorCode() != '00000')){
    var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
} else {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
$dbCon = null;
?>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: what do your error_logs/exceptions.txt say?

Comment: You should try formatting your SQL queries so people can actually read them instead of 500 character long single lines.

Comment: There is no error or exception. I even activate the MySQL log. It simply does not return any results.

Comment: @Jay This is not the same problem as the other since it was a typo problem in the table name. Please do not mark questions as duplicated too quickly.

Comment: Mark it too quickly? Until your comment here we could not have possibly known you had a typo in the table name.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Not me, but the question you link to that one. I still don't know where is my problem.

Comment: It is about how you're formatting your variables in the SQL statement. You should do the formatting in the `bindParam()` for each variable where the placeholder replaces the whole variable and any conditions surrounding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jay Blanchard,

> It is about how you're formatting your variables in the SQL statement.
>   You should do the formatting in the bindParam() for each variable
>   where the placeholder replaces the whole variable and any conditions
>   surrounding it.

I found the solution :

```
<?php
$dbCon = new PDO('mysql:host=SERVER_IP; port=3306; dbname=DATABASE',
    'root',
    'PASSWORD',
    array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
          PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING,
          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

$sql = 'SELECT art.AR_Ref AS AR_Ref, '
            . 'art.AR_Design AS AR_Design, '
            . 'art.AR_PrixVen AS AR_PrixVen, '
            . 'art.AR_CodeBarre AS AR_CodeBarre, '
            . 'af.CT_Num AS CT_Num, '
            . 'af.AF_RefFourniss AS AF_RefFourniss, '
            . 'ct.CT_Intitule AS CT_Intitule, '
            . 'art.CL_No1, '
            . 'art.CL_No2, '
            . 'art.CL_No3, '
            . 'art.CL_No4, '
            . 'MATCH (art.indexation) AGAINST (:saisie1) AS cpt, '
            . 'art.AR_Design REGEXP :saisie2 AS commencepar, '
            . 'art.AR_Design REGEXP :saisie3 AS contient '
     . 'FROM f_article art '
            . 'LEFT JOIN f_artfourniss af ON (art.AR_Ref = af.AR_Ref AND af.AF_Principal = 1) '
            . 'LEFT JOIN f_comptet ct ON (af.CT_Num = ct.CT_Num AND ct.CT_Type = 1) '
     . 'WHERE MATCH (art.indexation) AGAINST ((:saisie4) IN BOOLEAN MODE) '
     . 'ORDER BY commencepar DESC, '
            . 'contient DESC, '
            . 'cpt DESC, '
            . 'art.AR_Ref';
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
$saisie = 'iso';
$saisie1 = '+' . $saisie . '*';
$saisie2 = '^' . $saisie . '*';
$saisie3 = '.+' . $saisie . '.*';
$saisie4 = '+' . $saisie . '*';
$stmt->bindParam(':saisie1', $saisie1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':saisie2', $saisie2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':saisie3', $saisie3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':saisie4', $saisie4, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
if (($stmt->errorCode() != '00000')){
    var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
} else {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
$dbCon = null;
?>
```